# How can I instantiate PDO just once in my whole application, instead of everytime I want to make a query?

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

Currently, whenever I want to create a new function to make a different type of query, I have to instantiate PDO all over again... Even further, if I created another class could I use 'class B extends A', without having to make a whole new constructor?

```
class Site {
    var $driver;
    var $host;
    var $dbname;
    var $user;
    var $pass;

    public function __construct($driver, $host, $dbname, $user, $pass) {
        $this->driver = $driver;
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;        
    }
    public function jazz() {
        $d = new PDO("$this->driver:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", "$this->user","$this->pass");
        $d->query('SELECT name, price FROM products ORDER BY id ASC');
    }
    public function buzz() {
        $c = new PDO("$this->driver:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", "$this->user","$this->pass");
        $c->query('SELECT name, age FROM clients ORDER BY name ASC');
    }
}
```

Comment: Establish your connection outside of the class, then pass that connection as an argument to your class constructors

Comment: Sharing is caring. Create the handle once, keep it as property (in place of the individual connection params), or share it as global, or pass it in on construction or queries. (Though a class hierarchy on query types makes less sense.)

Comment: Instead of rolling your own solution to this, you really should investigate 
[development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) where this is built-in and production-ready.

Answer (score 2):

Just setup the connection in the constructor then you can use it in the class functions

```
class Site {
    var $driver;
    var $host;
    var $dbname;
    var $user;
    var $pass;
    private $conn;

    public function __construct($driver, $host, $dbname, $user, $pass) {
        $this->driver = $driver;
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;        
        $this->conn=  new PDO("$this->driver:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", "$this->user","$this->pass");
    }

    public function jazz() {
        $this->conn->query('SELECT name, price FROM products ORDER BY id ASC');
    }

    public function buzz() {

        $this->conn->query('SELECT name, age FROM clients ORDER BY name ASC');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Site {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function jazz() {
        $this->db->query(...);
    }

}

$db   = new PDO(...);
$site = new Site($db);
$site->jazz();
```

It's called *dependency injection*.